# SQL Server Management Studio color en palabras clave

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Buenas:
Tengo instalado el Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2016 versión 13.0.15900.1 y por más que busco no consigo hacer que las palabras clave se me pongan en distinto color.
Leí por ahí que tenía que habilitar el Intellisense pero lo tengo habilitado y sigue sin ir.
En [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) he mirado a ver si habían preguntas similares y las dos que hay no están resueltas pero aún así he probado lo que ponía y sigo igual.
He intentado exportar la configuración del administrador, tal y como me dijo Mauricio Arias Olave en uno de sus comentarios y me sale el error que se muestra bajo.
[image: Imagen de configuración]
También comprobé (aunque no lo había puesto), que la palabra clave estuviera en otro color. 
[image: Error al importar configuración]

Después de unas pruebas, me he fijado también que cada vez que elijo un color en el texto sin formato, todo el texto aparece en ese color. Es como si cada vez que abro una consulta o un procedimiento almacenado, lo que se muestra fuera un texto sin formato. Cómo puedo cambiar esto?

Gracias.
Un saludo

Comment: Necesitaría que me salieran esos colores aunque sea en las vistas y los procedimientos.

Comment: Maria, revisa esta [respuesta _en inglés_](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/73933) o la respuesta que acabo de colocar. En todo caso, te recomiendo investigar un poco mas sobre cómo puedes hacer esto.

Answer (score 1):

Para cambiar el color de las palabras reservadas, debes entrar al Menú

**`Tools`** `-->` **`Options`** `-->` **`Fonts and Colors`** `-->` **`Display Items`** `-->` **`Keyword`**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso, yo seleccioné el color rojo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para regresar a la configuración predeterminada, es justo como lo menciona Mauricio Arias en su [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/60344/16841).

Comment: Tengo lo de las palabras claves como tú aunque yo soy más de azul, jeje. Lo he puesto en la pregunta porque ya lo había comprobado pero se me había olvidado ponerlo (qué despiste).

Comment: @Maria ya no entendí, no era esto lo que necesitabas? Cambiar las palabras clave de color? :)

Comment: Necesito que salgan pero a pesar de tener esa opción marcada, no me aparecen en distinto color cuando hago una vista o un procedimiento almacenado. Ahora mismo me sale todo en el mismo color, que en mi caso es en negro sobre fondo blanco.

Answer (score 0):

Revise este [enlace](https://mikesdatawork.wordpress.com/2016/06/04/ssms-2016-fonts-and-colors-what-is-what/) que contiene gran información sobre las configuraciones de colores, fuentes y demás aspectos de SQL Management Server 2016.

También puedes considerar "[restaurar la configuración](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/making-ssms-pretty-my-dark-theme/)", siguiendo estos pasos:

> Tools > Import and Export Settigns > Reset all settings

*Captura de pantalla de SQL Management Server 2012 - pero el proceso sería el mismo*.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: He mirado las páginas que indicas y he restaurado la configuración y sigo igual. Tengo puesto como que las palabras clave me las ponga en color Azul (el que viene por defecto) pero aunque intente hacer una Vista o Procedimiento nuevo, o incluso cuando abro uno que ya está creado, sigo sin tener resaltadas las palabras clave.
He visto que tengo también la última versión instalada del SSMS.

Comment: @Maria, ¿has cerrado y abierto SSMS para guardar cambios? Abre además SSMS como administrador.

Comment: He cerrado y abierto y sigo igual. He abierto el SSMS como administrador y sí que sale todo bien pero cuando lo vuelvo a abrir en modo "normal" sigo igual. Y no puedo abrirlo siempre como administrador porque no tengo los permisos para poder hacerlo. @MauricioAriasOlave hay algún modo para borrar el fichero de la configuración y que se vuelva a crear? Porque al resetearlo me he quedado igual.

Comment: @Maria, puedes exportar la configuración de otro SSMS. ¿tienes acceso a otro equipo que tenga SSMS? sigue los mismos pasos que he descrito en mi respuesta para exportar la configuración y aplícala a la versión de SMSS en tu equipo. _Por si de pronto no has hecho esta prueba_, entra de nuevo como administrador a SSMS, realiza las configuraciones y guarda los cambios. Luego ingresa de nuevo a SSMS como un usuario normal. Ademas, te recomiendo investigar si hay preguntas similares en el sitio en inglés _[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/)_ y actualiza tu pregunta.

Comment: He hecho lo que me has dicho y sigo igual. No sé si debía pero he puesto las pruebas que he hecho en la pregunta para que la gente lo vea mejor.

Comment: @Maria, es bueno que hayas actualizado tu pregunta. Así es como se debe hacer. lamento no tener mas cómo ayudarte. Espero que encuentres la solución y _(una vez la encuentres)_ puedas [aceptar la respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) o [responder a tu propia pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Saludos.

Comment: Igualmente agradezco tu ayuda porque al menos he descartado cosas. Si encuentro como solucionarlo (y no es desinstalando y volviendo a instalar el ssms), pondré la respuesta por si a alguien más le ocurre como a mí.